# How do I use an SQL element in WHERE command which contains spaces?

Tags: mysql, sql

Note that my table files are stored in .csv format.

Here are the elements of my table 1(TABLE1):

Food
Food Price
Food Order
Food Quantity

Here are the elements of my second table(TABLE2):

Food Order
Food Delivery time

Here's what I want to do:

```
SELECT 'Food','Food Price','Food Order','Food Quantity','Food Delivery time'
FROM TABLE1,TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.'Food Order'==TABLE2.'Food Order';
```

Also after that I want to compute another metric which is defined as 'Quantity Units' and is equal to 'Food Price'/'Food Quantity'.

I am totally new to SQL so do let me know if there's any syntax mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Enclose the column names in backticks (`), not single quotes

Comment: Null safe equal in mysql is <=>. Not an errot but you should use explicit (JOIN) rather than comma joins.AND food_order(and possibly other columns) will give an ambiguous column error. In the case of possible ambiquity(of source table) qualify column name with table name.